# SVG in img tag sizing inconsistent, movement seems like dancing

Tags: css, svg, mobile, rendering

## Background

I am developing a PhoneGap/Cordova app that should run on iOS and Android devices, and uses SVG images embedded as `<img/>` tags, using HTML attributes `width=""` and `height=""` to set their dimensions, and `style="left: ...px; top: ...px; zoom: ...;"` to set their relative position, with a zoom coefficient that is uniform between multiple image objects.

My problem is that when zooming in and out, the images are rendered with different sizes, both in Safari and in Chrome. This can also be seen in the desktop versions of these browsers, and I think I can narrow it down to a rounding issue with respect to the `left` and `top` CSS property. The problem is aggravated when using fractional values for the `zoom` CSS property, and the `width` and `height` HTML attributes.

[I have created a demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/d4x33eLa/19/) and a [downloadable version here](https://gist.github.com/kwikwag/74b991206c5fd197c70a6ec2c02fd238/). In this demo, I have used two SVG images, identical except for their fill color, which I use for color contrast. There are three pairs in the demo: the top-most uses a fractional `zoom` value, the middle uses fractional `width` and `height` values, and the last uses round multiples of the `width` and `height` values. There is a button that starts an animations that simply moves all images to the right, by a single pixel in each step. It'll be easy to notice in Chrome that the middle images jiggle substantially, while a little harder to notice changes in the other two - but they are also there. I'm using Windows 10 and Chrome 65.0 -- though I can see variations of the problem in Firefox and Edge as well (though -- they are rendered differently).

Here is an animation of the demo. Note that all I am changing between frames is the `left` position of all images - and doing so in a uniform manner.

[image: dancing SVGs demo]

## Actual question

For my application, the images must have consistent rendering across `zoom` levels and in different positions on the page. When changing the `zoom`, `left` and `top` properties smoothly, the images should change dimensions and position smoothly, respectfully. They should not change dimensions when changing the `left` and `top` properties. Is there a method that ensures that when multiple images use the same (possibly fractional) `width` and `height` values, but varying `left` and `top` positions, they will be rendered identically? Is there a way to ensure that smooth transition of the `zoom` property results in smooth rendering?

## Guidelines for an answer

A proper answer would either explain why this is not possible using current browsers, pointing to a confirmed bug report that describes this problem and shows that it affects popular devices in either platform; or present an alternative way to size and position the images, while retaining the possibility to use fractional values, and that obtains uniformity and smooth zoom transitions when all images use the same dimensions.

Thanks for any help you may offer!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the `zoom` property support is not quite consistent between the browsers (as you can see here https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom). Try rather the `transform: scale()` property:

```js
function budgeRight() {
   var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
   imgs = Array.prototype.slice.apply(imgs);
   imgs.forEach(function(img) { 
      var left = parseInt(img.style.left);
      
      img.style.left = (left + 1).toString() + "px"; 
    });
}

var interval = null;
var button = document.getElementById('button-click-me');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
  }
  else {
    interval = setInterval(budgeRight, 500);
  }
});
```

```css
img { position: absolute; }
body { background-color: #000; }
```

```html
<img style="-webkit-transform: scale(2.3); -moz-transform: scale(2.3); -ms-transform: scale(2.3); -o-transform: scale(2.3); transform: scale(2.3); -webkit-transform-origin: top left; -moz-transform-origin: top left; -ms-transform-origin: top left; -o-transform-origin: top left; transform-origin: top left; left: 41px; top: 25px;" src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kwikwag/74b991206c5fd197c70a6ec2c02fd238/raw/3f4070dbb97c69f716ad6b32ca5f6abd1f4fd702/rect_white.svg?sanitize=true">
<img style="-webkit-transform: scale(2.3); -moz-transform: scale(2.3); -ms-transform: scale(2.3); -o-transform: scale(2.3); transform: scale(2.3); -webkit-transform-origin: top left; -moz-transform-origin: top left; -ms-transform-origin: top left; -o-transform-origin: top left; transform-origin: top left; left: 40px; top: 25px;" src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kwikwag/74b991206c5fd197c70a6ec2c02fd238/raw/3f4070dbb97c69f716ad6b32ca5f6abd1f4fd702/rect_red.svg?sanitize=true">
<img style="-webkit-transform: scale(2.3); -moz-transform: scale(2.3); -ms-transform: scale(2.3); -o-transform: scale(2.3); transform: scale(2.3); -webkit-transform-origin: top left; -moz-transform-origin: top left; -ms-transform-origin: top left; -o-transform-origin: top left; transform-origin: top left; left: 31px; top: 35px;" width="9.35" height="23.35" src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kwikwag/74b991206c5fd197c70a6ec2c02fd238/raw/3f4070dbb97c69f716ad6b32ca5f6abd1f4fd702/rect_red.svg?sanitize=true">
<img style="-webkit-transform: scale(2.3); -moz-transform: scale(2.3); -ms-transform: scale(2.3); -o-transform: scale(2.3); transform: scale(2.3); -webkit-transform-origin: top left; -moz-transform-origin: top left; -ms-transform-origin: top left; -o-transform-origin: top left; transform-origin: top left; left: 32px; top: 35px;" width="9.35" height="23.35" src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kwikwag/74b991206c5fd197c70a6ec2c02fd238/raw/3f4070dbb97c69f716ad6b32ca5f6abd1f4fd702/rect_white.svg?sanitize=true">
<img style="left: 91px; top: 130px;" width="18" height="42" src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kwikwag/74b991206c5fd197c70a6ec2c02fd238/raw/3f4070dbb97c69f716ad6b32ca5f6abd1f4fd702/rect_red.svg?sanitize=true">
<img style="left: 94px; top: 130px;" width="18" height="42" src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kwikwag/74b991206c5fd197c70a6ec2c02fd238/raw/3f4070dbb97c69f716ad6b32ca5f6abd1f4fd702/rect_white.svg?sanitize=true">
<button id="button-click-me">Click me</button>
```

Notice I added `transform-origin: top left`, to scale each image from its top left corner.
And I also used all the vendor-prefixes `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, etc. to have a maximum compatibility on these 2 properties...

Comment: Valentin, thank you for your reply. While the `zoom` property is indeed inconsistent between browsers, my questions is about the consistency of its behavior within a certain type of browser. Your solution, to use the `scale` property, still exhibits inconsistencies in sizing, albeit much minor, in my browser (Windows Chrome). So I am compelled to not accept the answer. If you can show this is a confirmed bug in browsers, I'll take it.